# Prevent default nested scrolling behavior with electron webview

Tags: javascript, html, webview, electron

**Case:** I have an electron app which loads a webpage inside a webview. The webview is inside a container which is itself scrollable.

**Current behavior:** When scrolling the webview, if the I reach the bottom of the page where the webview cannot scroll anymore, and if I continue scrolling, the container which contains the webview starts scrolling.

**What I want:** I don't want the container to scroll in this case.

**What I have tried:** I tried capturing the containers *wheel* event. The event is being fired in normal scrolling, but not in this particular case which I want to capture. I've also tried injecting a preload script in the webview and listening to wheel events on the document. The wheel events are not being fired in any case in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is called "scroll chaining" and is sometimes unwanted. It should be possible to disable it at the CSS level by using the [overscroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior) property applied to the container.

For instance, if the HTML container is `<div class="webview-container"> </div>`:

```
div.webview-container { overscroll-behavior: contain; };
```

To be on the safe side, you may want to try other combinations of values (`auto`, `contain`, `none`) as well...